# Группировка элементов коллекции без Stream API

Tags: java

Есть метод, который группирует элементы коллекции из нескольким полям.

```
public void test() {
    List<Item> itemsList = ...//Чтение из XML;

    Map<List<Object>, List<Item>> groupBy =
            itemsList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    i -> Arrays.asList(i.id, i.city, i.order_status)));

    for (Map.Entry<List<Object>, List<Item>> t : groupBy.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(t.getKey());
        for (Item item : t.getValue()) {
            System.out.println("    " + item);
        }
    }
}
```

А как сделать такое же без Stream API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто создается мапа с явным указанием типа ключа и значений, в цикле проходишь по списку и добавляешь элементы в мапу при помощи [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) -- этот метод при необходимости создаёт новое или возвращает существующее значение-список, для которого можно сразу же вызвать метод `List:add`.
При этом лучше использовать `LinkedHashMap`, чтобы порядок элементов в ней был стабильный (`HashMap` порядка не гарантирует).

```java
public static Map<List<Object>, List<Item>> groupBy(List<Item> list) {
    Map<List<Object>, List<Item>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Item item : list) {
        List<Object> key = Arrays.asList(item.getId(), item.getCity(), item.getOrderStatus());
        map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(item);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Следует отметить, что вместо списка объектов правильнее было бы использовать некий промежуточный класс, для которого нужно корректно переопределить методы `hashCode` и `equals`.  Это достаточно просто сделать при помощи кортежей `record`, официально поддерживаемых с Java 16, или Lombok-аннотаций `@Data` / `@AllArgsConstructor`.

```java
enum OrderStatus {NEW, PROCESSING, COMPLETED, CANCELED};

// определены конструктор, геттеры без префикса `get`, hashCode / equals, toString
record MyKey(long id, String city, OrderStatus status) {
    public MyKey(Item item) {
        this(item.getId(), item.getCity(), item.getOrderStatus());
    }
}

public static Map<MyKey, List<Item>> groupBy(List<Item> list) {
    Map<MyKey, List<Item>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    list.forEach(item -> map
        .computeIfAbsent(new MyKey(item), k -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(item)
    );

    // отладочный вывод
    map.forEach((key, val) -> {
        System.out.println(key);
        val.forEach(item -> System.out.println("\t" + item));
    });

    return map;
}
```

При желании создание такой группировки можно параметризовать для любого ключа, если передавать некую функцию-конвертор [`Function<Item, Key>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), в последнем примере такой функцией был конструктор кортежа `MyKey(Item item)`.  Например, для генерации ключа-списка можно было бы определить отдельный фабричный метод:

```java
// MyClass
public static List<Object> keyIdCityStatus(Item item) {
    return Arrays.asList(item.getId(), item.getCity(), item.getOrderStatus());
}
```

Параметризованный метод выглядит так:

```java
public static<K> Map<K, List<Item>> groupBy(Function<Item, K> keyBuilder, List<Item> list) {
    Map<K, List<Item>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    list.forEach(item -> map
        .computeIfAbsent(keyBuilder.apply(item), k -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(item)
    );

    return map;
}
```

Соответственно вызывать его можно для любого ключа:

```java
// ссылка на фабричный метод MyClass::keyIdCityStatus
Map<List<Object>, List<Item>> keyListMap = groupBy(MyClass::keyIdCityStatus, list);

// группировка по двум полям с помощью лямбды
Map<List<Object>, List<Item>> byIdAndStatus = groupBy(
    item -> List.of(item.getId(), item.getOrderStatus()), 
    list
);

// ссылка на конструктор MyKey::new
Map<MyKey, List<Item>> keyRecordMap = groupBy(MyKey::new, list);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можно объяснить почему лучше использовать промежуточный класс? Чтобы корректно в нем создать метод hasCode и правильное сравнение задать в equals или есть и другие подводные камни использования полей при группировке как в моем примере? Со Stream API мало работал, но сейчас понимаю что они очень облегчают если уметь пользоваться.

Comment: В принципе, здесь переплетаются как вопросы стиля -- иметь список объектов в качестве ключа (фактически сырой список) -- это быстрое и "грязное" решение, в котором прежде всего убирается строгая типизация, присущая Java.  Второй момент -- использование "своего" объекта позволит (пере)определить методы `hashCode` / `equals` так, как нужно вам.  В реализациях списков `Arrays.asList` / `List.of` используются все элементы в обоих методах, унаследованных от `AbstractList`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ..

Comment: В этом ответе используется не Stream API как таковое, а некоторые расширения для функционального программирования, появившиеся в Java 8 в 2014 году, типа функционального интерфейса `Function`, ссылок на методы, лямбда-выражений в методах `Map::computeIfAbsent`, `Map::forEach`, `List::forEach`.  Понятно, что такой код выглядит немного непривычно, по сравнению с классическими циклами `for` / `for-each`, но к примеру под капотом в `Iterable::forEach` используется тот же цикл, который опять-таки сводится к итератору :)

Comment: С обычными циклами я пытался сделать и не даже смог понять как сгруппировать по нескольким полям. Stream облегчил задачу.

Comment: Правда, переопределять методы `hashCode / equals` для класса-ключа тоже следует с умом -- недавно был вопрос о ключе, в котором для всех объектов одинаковый хэш-код [Как происходит вставка нового элемента с коллизией в hashmap?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1500827/), т.е. можно сознательно ухудшить производительность мапы, так как для при обращении к любому ключу придется перебирать их все.

Comment: А при использовании record все равно рекомендуется переопределять методы equals и hashCode или можно не переопределять? И если переопределять метод equals достаточно ли переопределить его следующим образом: @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

Я так сделал и проверил группировку, вроде нормально.

Comment: [Do you need to override hashCode() and equals() for records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719589/): Нет, переопределение `equals` / `hashCode` необязательно; для кортежей есть дополнительное условие, что копия кортежа должна быть равна исходному кортежу (см. [`Record::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Понял, спасибо.